# update inside array in cloudfirestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

so i want to update inside the array

here is the database look like

[image]

```
               static Future<void> EditObat(
               String? namarsgm,
               int nominal,
               idobat,
               ) async 
               {
                  await Database.doc(hospital).update(
                  {
                   'Obat'[idobat]: FieldValue.arrayUnion({'Banyak' : 
                     FieldValue.increment(nominal)}),
                  },
                  );
               }
```

So i want to increase the value 'Banyak', and after research, i still haven't make it
anyone know how to solve this ?

Comment: There is no way to update an item in an array in Firestore. You will have to read the document, update the array in your application code, and then write the entire array back to the database.